# Update 2 Tables after Add, Edit or Delete

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am currently building an ASP.NET MVC application that allows admin users to add, edit and delete users. For the application, I have 3 different database tables called AdminUsers, Users and AuditChanges. Every time a user is added, edited or deleted, I would like it to update the Users table as necessary, which isn't a problem. On top of this, I would also like the application write an entry into the AuditChanges table which states which admin it was that processed the function, which user was updated and also what type of function was processed e.g. an edit or delete. What I am currently struggling with is updating more than one database and was wondering if this was possible?

For Example:

If I was to access my Create User page and add a user I would like my User table to look like this:

```
UserID          BranchNumber
U123456         1234
```

But then I would also like my AuditChanges table to look like this:

```
AdminID         UserID        BranchNumber       Type
U654321         U123456       1234               Add
U235874         U192395       4321               Edit
U827734         U283849       9999               Delete
```

This is so I am able to keep track of who has been updating the Users table and what they have been updating it with.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Users user = db.Users.Find(id);
    return View(user);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Users user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(user);
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Users user, AuditChanges changes)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Users.Add(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(user);
}

public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    Users user = db.Users.Find(id);
        return View(user);
}

    //
    // POST: /Errors/Delete/5

[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    Users user = db.Users.Find(id);
    db.Users.Remove(user);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**Models**

```
[Table("CTP_Users")]
public class Users
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LogonId { get; set; }

    public string BranchNumber { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
[Table("CTP_Users")]
public class Users
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LogonId { get; set; }

    public string BranchNumber { get; set; }
}
```

If you require anymore information then let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could be easily done by having a method that takes the AdminID, UserID and UpdateMethod and logs that information to the AuditChanges table; and the method would be called from the Add/Update actions in your Controller

Comment: You can the override `SaveChanges` method of `DbContext` to automatically do this.  See this tutorial: http://www.jigar.net/articles/viewhtmlcontent344.aspx

Comment: If you want an easy solution, you could create a Stored Procedure on the database side and make the SP do all that is required. Your code would then only have a single, simple, command call.

Comment: @BrianPayne: I guess you meant to say a `trigger`.

Comment: @BrianPayne that completely defeats the EF purpose that is not writing any SQL at all, but do it automatically.

Comment: @KosalaW not, he means an stored procedure: the triggger wouldn't have a way to know the AdminUserId by intercepting modifications to the Users table.

Comment: No, I meant a `Stored Procedure`, @Kosala, but only because I belatedly saw the Entity Framework tag, which I do not use. A `trigger` could work, but even simple triggers can cause errors that are not readily apparent from your code.

Comment: @D.M Try to implement your logic in a separate class, not inside the controller's action: that will help you organize your code better. Also try using view models specific to each action, not directly EF entities: doing so you're strongly tying your interface to your database. This will complicate your application, even if you think that having more classes is more complicated, is all the way round.

Comment: @D.M and now that you have some feedback, try something, and update your question if you have concrete problems. This question is "too broad" to keep it open (too much possible good answers).

Comment: @JotaBe _Quote:the triggger wouldn't have a way to know the AdminUserId by intercepting modifications to the Users table_. There is no need for a trigger to know what the AdminUserID is. All it needs to know is whether anyone performed an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE operation on the users table. Which includes someone modifying the data in the users table using a sql statement. If you go for any other solution which is based on C#, you will not be able to cover the **modification done to users table outside of the main application** aspect.

Comment: @BrianPayne: _Quote: A trigger could work, but even simple triggers can cause errors that are not readily apparent from your code_ I used to think the same way about 10years ago. But when you know more about the sqlserver, you will start appreciating what triggers can do. As I said before, you will not be able to track any modifications done to the `users` table, outside of the main application if you do not use a trigger for this purpose. However, I highly recommend to get the trigger reviewed by an experienced SQL developer and test it as much as possible before releasing in to production.

Comment: @KosalaW 1) How would a trigger add a row in the log table that has the **AdminUserID** with a trigger for a table tha doesn't have that column? 2) A trigger can be easyly overlooked, because it isn't implemented in the application, which is what you usually debug, test, and so on 3) if you're afraid that the user table is modified by something else, that means that you have a bad designed architecture. 4) If you use EF for data access, why using triggers? Beside triggers are db specific, and you couldn't change the backend 5) you've got to do special config to use mugrations with triggers ...

Comment: @JotaBe : This is a separate discussion. 1) This can be done quite easily. 2) I sort of agree with that; however when it comes to complex systems, there can be many things that can be overlooked. For an example, replication, scheduled agent jobs etc. So it is important to document them and have designated people looking after them. 3) That's not a correct statement. Think about system migrations, likewise there can be many situations where you have to do it. When you start developing systems that cater to millions of users you will realise how much of work is actually required. contd....

Comment: @JotaBe: Contd. 4) Nowadays developers tend to overlook many things due to EF. For an example, _it is ok not to have indexes, because we are using EF._ 5) So, why is it a problem?

Comment: @JotaBe: Conted..4) _Quote: Beside triggers are db specific, and you couldn't change the backend_ . But did not you recommend using Stored Procs? How come SPs are not db specific but triggers are?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96650/discussion-between-jotabe-and-kosala-w).